# Repeat code in android

Tags: java, android

I want an app which changes background color when pressing a button. After 500 ms, I want to change background color to black for 2000ms. And then repeat whole process again, until user terminates that.

I have following code but its not working as I think it should.

```
private void set() {
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    set(); // can I do that?
                }
            });             
        }
    }, 500);    
}
```

Can someone point me to right direction how can I do that? So I want:

1. Execute some code
2. After X time passed by , I want to execute another code and it should stay that way for X amount of time
3. Repeat process until user cancels that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work I think

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable turnBlack = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        goWhite();
    }};

    Runnable turnWhite = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
            goBlack();
        }};

public void goBlack() {
    handler.postDelayed(turnBlack, 500);
}

public void goWhite() {
    handler.postDelayed(turnWhite, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier way to do this using AnimationDrawable:

```
    AnimationDrawable drawable = new AnimationDrawable();
    ColorDrawable color1 = new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW);
    ColorDrawable color2 = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);

    // First color yellow for 500 ms
    drawable.addFrame(color1, 500);

    // Second color black for 2000 ms
    drawable.addFrame(color2, 2000);

    // Set if animation should loop. In this case yes it will
    drawable.setOneShot(false);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setBackground(drawable);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonLan).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start animation
            ((AnimationDrawable)v.getBackground()).start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but i have some other things to do in switching code, so only switching colors won't work.